# How to save a plot using orca when the plot have some Arabic or Persian letter?

Tags: r, plotly, orca

I am trying to save a plot as png in R, but when I use Arabic letters in plot the saved plot doesn't have any good structure?

```r
ds <- data.frame(labels = c("سامان", "احمد", "یوسف","A1", "B2", "C3"),values = c(10, 40, 60,50,40,10))
 p=plot_ly(ds, labels = ds$labels, values = ds$values, type = "pie") 
plotly::orca(p, file="p.png")
```